# Loop Multidimensional array in Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need to loop in a mulitidemnsional array being consumed in an outbound API. After consuming the API in a controller, I need to insert the looped records in a Model.

So, the response recieved from the external API is the following:

[image]

So, what Im doing in my controller function is the following:

```
public function index()
{

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://api', [
        'headers' => [
             'x-authtoken' => '0275d',
             'cache-control' => 'no-cache'],
             'decode_content' => false
    ]);

     //get body content
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    foreach ( $data['content']['Propiedades'] as $propiedades )
        {
            $id = Arr::get($propiedades, 'Id');
            $Moneda = Arr::get($propiedades, 'Precio.Moneda');
            $Precio = Arr::get($propiedades, 'Precio.Valor')
        }

}
```

The problem is that im looping just one instance of "propiedades" array.

[image]

**1. How can I loop all "propiedades" array and retrieve key values from it?**

**2. How can access each "propiedades" array to the next nested array and bring back those nested values realted to the first array level?** 
For example, my result must be for each property record:

Propiedades.Id

Propiedades.Precio.Moneda

Propiedades.Precio.Valor

**3. Ones I get all the "propiedades" with their values, do I need to create an array to insert those records in a Model? How do I pass the data to the model? My Models will have the structure as the array recevied from the API with the corresponding child entities for "propiedades"**

---

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Comment: Can you attach a full json example so I can work with it in order to help you? I'm interested by the content of the $body variable.

Comment: Sure, I havee uploaded the requested variable contento in : [Link](https://ufile.io/pn1go)

The attached file is the same output as the first screenshot I pasted in the post.

Thanks for you help @MathieuBour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i saved whole json into file and then decoded it and printed it all out, i see no complexity in this, it is all looping out as you wanted i checked in local and in my personal production server, data is looping out as you wanted,

Now if you're still having problem specifically in looping then you need to debug more like Is json decoded properly ? something like that. That's my last try for this question specifically looping part, if there is any other issue apart from looping problem then please let me know. :)

```
    Route::get('/test',function(){
    $content = json_decode(\File::get(public_path().'/custom.txt'),true);
    // Actual Content
    //dump($content);

    // First and Best Approach
    foreach ($content['content']['Propiedades'] as $key){
        dump($key['Id']);
        dump($key['Titulo']);
        dump($key['Descripcion']);
        dump($key['Precio']);
        dump($key['Operacion']);
        dump($key['EstadoPublicacion']);
        dump($key['Ubicacion']);
        dump($key['UbicacionCadena']);
        dump($key['TipoPropiedad']);
        dump($key['Direccion']);
        dump($key['RoundDireccion']);
        dump($key['Calle']);
        dump($key['Numero']);
        dump($key['Latitud']);
        dump($key['Longitud']);
        dump($key['ImagenPrincipal']);
        dump($key['SuperficieTotal']);
        dump($key['Dormitorios']);
        dump($key['Banios']);
        dump($key['CantidadAmbientes']);
        dump($key['AtributosDestacadosListado']);
        dump($key['Usuario']);
        dump($key['IdUbicacion']);
        dump($key['Imagenes']);
        dump($key['Sucursal']);
        dump($key['FechaCreacion']);
        dump($key['FechaModificacion']);
        dump($key['PublicaPrecio']);
        dump($key['PathFicha']);
    }

    // Second and Long Approach

//    foreach ($content as $key => $value){
//        if($key === 'status'){
//            //dump($value);
//        }elseif($key === 'content'){
//            //dump($value);
//            foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1){
//                if($key1 === 'cantidadPropiedades'){
//                    //dump($value1);
//                }elseif($key1 === 'cantidadPropiedades'){
//                    //dump($value1);
//                }elseif($key1 === 'Propiedades'){
//                    //dump($value1);
//                    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
//                        //dump($value2);
//                        dump($value2['Id']);
//                        dump($value2['Titulo']);
//                        dump($value2['Descripcion']);
//                        dump($value2['Precio']);
//                        dump($value2['Operacion']);
//                        dump($value2['EstadoPublicacion']);
//                        dump($value2['Ubicacion']);
//                        dump($value2['UbicacionCadena']);
//                        dump($value2['TipoPropiedad']);
//                        dump($value2['Direccion']);
//                        dump($value2['RoundDireccion']);
//                        dump($value2['Calle']);
//                        dump($value2['Numero']);
//                        dump($value2['Latitud']);
//                        dump($value2['Longitud']);
//                        dump($value2['ImagenPrincipal']);
//                        dump($value2['SuperficieTotal']);
//                        dump($value2['Dormitorios']);
//                        dump($value2['Banios']);
//                        dump($value2['CantidadAmbientes']);
//                        dump($value2['AtributosDestacadosListado']);
//                        dump($value2['Usuario']);
//                        dump($value2['IdUbicacion']);
//                        dump($value2['Imagenes']);
//                        dump($value2['Sucursal']);
//                        dump($value2['FechaCreacion']);
//                        dump($value2['FechaModificacion']);
//                        dump($value2['PublicaPrecio']);
//                        dump($value2['PathFicha']);
//                    }
//                }elseif($key1 === 'FiltrosAplicados'){
//                    //dump($value1);
//                }elseif($key1 === 'FiltrosDisponibles'){
//                    //dump($value1);
//                }elseif($key1 === 'OrdenamientosAplicados'){
//                    //dump($value1);
//                }elseif($key1 === 'OrdenamientosDisponibles'){
//                    //dump($value1);
//                }elseif($key1 === 'Paginado'){
//                    //dump($value1);
//                }
//            }
//        }elseif($key === 'errors'){
//            //dump($value);
//        }
//    }
    dd("STOP");
})->name('test');
```

I hope this Helps.

Comment: Thanks @ViperTecPro ! I understood your approach and that works for part of my issue.The other part is that with your code and mine, I just access 1 element of the 1 level array called "Propiedades", it doesn't loop to all the elementsin that array. Also I need to loop child arrays from "propiedades" if they exists to bring values as I mentioned in my first post. Regards

Comment: i don't understand why is it showing one, i tested with small piece of code with same array you've mentioned, well i updated code,Also please try nested foreach to work with complex array structure, i'm little short on time i will be back soon.

Comment: I'm Back, please give it a try my updated code and if there is any issue let me know.

Comment: Thanks @ViperTecPro, let me test ypu code with mine and I will update. Regards

Comment: That's great i will be waiting

Comment: your approach falied in my code with error: **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

I left the code as yoy send it:

`foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if($key === 'content'){
                foreach ($value as $arr1){
                    foreach ($arr1 as $p){
                        dump($p['Id']); // HERE YOU CAN GET ALL THE ELEMENTS IN Propiedades[]
                    }
                }
            }
        }`

This is the error screenhot: [Link](https://ufile.io/329n7)

Why are you using $data as $key => $value instead of $data as $key => $value ?

Comment: Error link does't work please update and can you send me all array in text so that i can test and i used $value because the array you are receiving in that value contains array so that's why

Comment: sure, you can now download it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B8iuTPE3gmulBWRKGFhfqIcUQ5HnGYBH

Please tell me ones you donwload it so I can remove the file. Also please look at the json file because it looks it paginating some data, do you know so I can move into the next record blocks? Regards

Comment: Downloaded you can remove the link now okay i get it now working on it. You please keep on trying and let me know if you got anything to resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks file removed! Regards I can't still access the child records of the first array (Propiedades) and even below are more arrays I can't reach.

Comment: I can't access child properties array and the nested values below them, any clue? Thanks for you time!